# Set variable name as href id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

It might sound very stupid to you guys but I am having trouble setting a javascript variable name as href id.

Code:

```
dataReceived =data[i].name;
$("#someDiv").append("<a href=\"#\" class=bookLink>"+dataReceived+"</a>" +"<br>");
```

I want to set id of the above link as dataReceived. My intention is to read the link id which will change depending on value of dataReceived and then use that ID to do whatever I want. Any help is appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: You want to set the link’s ID to `dataReceived`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently setting dataReceived to the display text of the  tag.

If you want it to be the href, you need to use

```
dataReceived =data[i].name;
$("#someDiv").append("<a href=\"" + dataReceived + "\" class=bookLink>"+dataReceived+"</a>" +"<br>");
```

If you want it to be the ID, you need to use

```
dataReceived =data[i].name;
$("#someDiv").append("<a href=\"#\"  id  = \"" + dataReceived + "\" class=bookLink>"+dataReceived+"</a>" +"<br>");
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than building a string like that, you're better off building the element as an object, then appending it to its container - this will help with formatting, avoid quote errors, and make it easier to assign attributes. So it would be something like:

```
var $lnk = jQuery("<a></a>")
   .attr("href", "#")
   .attr("id", dataReceived)
   .html("whatever you want the link to read")
   .addClass("bookLink");

jQuery("#someDiv").append($lnk).append("<br>");
```

Just be careful when assigning text to the id like that - you want to make sure your id is meaningful and unique.

Comment: Didn't know of this way. Will try it too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this will help

```
dataReceived =data[i].name;
$("#someDiv").append('<a href="#" class="bookLink" id="'+dataReceived+'">'+dataReceived+'</a><br>');
```

so if `dataReceived  = 'someID_1'`  this code will render

```
<a href="#" class="bookLink" id="someID_1">someID_1</a><br>
```